# pack nodejs app without GUI

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I have develop an app bases on nodejs.
It is a command line app without gui
Can this be packed to binary execute file using node-webkit?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that I understand the question, it is not question wether it will wrap non gui app but if the app itself is written in a way that will work as intended and has sufficient permissions to do whatever it is supposed to do.

Read here about ways to wrap it :

https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps

And for other stuff, you need to know if it will be allowed to do on your local OS what it does on your server (access disk in particular way, run apps etc), also if it is CLI app, arm it with needed interface, and implement debugging mode to it so you can find out what is happening when smt goes wrong.